# Saving images or pdfs in db4o

Tags: pdf, image, file, db4o

I know it is not a good thing to save files in a relational databas.
But how about in a objectdatabase?
Is it still a bad idea or are they more adapted for this kind of operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had some experience storing the images in a special blob field in db4o. It works reasonably well, looking at the db4o forums you could learn more about experiences. Some links:

- http://developer.db4o.com/forums/thread/48512.aspx
- http://developer.db4o.com/tags/Blob/default.aspx
- http://developer.db4o.com/forums/thread/30107.aspx

The blobs are stored in external files outside of the db4o yap file.

Comment: Ok, great. I guess that it doesn't matter if it is an image or pdf or...?

Comment: It depends on how you want to show it, if you'd like to have your image be a property of your entity and you want to use winforms and use databinding, you could be in for a hard road (all though maybe that has changed). But if you just want the files out for a website, it won't matter what you put into it.